# Yii PHPUnit Selenium: assertChecked false does not work

Tags: php, selenium, yii, phpunit

I am trying to set up assertion for unchecked checkbox. Checked assertion works fine when I use:

```
$this->assertChecked('css=#element', true);
```

When I want to test unchecked chekbox with

```
$this->assertChecked('css=#element', false);
```

I get this error:

```
Failed command: assertChecked('css=#element', '')
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.`assertChecked ( locator )` - true if the checkbox is checked, false otherwise

2.`assertNotChecked ( locator )` - true if the checkbox is unchecked, false otherwise

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I'm not able to use negative case in any of these assertions. Every time I use assertChecked('css=#element', false), I get that error. The same thing is with any of assert methods where we can put true/false parameter

Comment: Sorry, this is actually correct answer. There's no second parameter. Thank you!